# Notification in Java thread synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

When there are multiple threads in waiting state; and if I call notify() rather than calling notifyAll() Which one is going to be notified among several threads in waiting state?

Comment: I don't know the answer for this, but a good idea is to check out the  java.concurrent package, it can do a lot of things for you.

Comment: @Fernando He/she's not asking how to do but how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's undefined behavior. Anyone could be picked up. From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29):

> If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be
>   awakened. **The choice is arbitrary** and occurs at the discretion of the
>   implementation.

And yes, this can lead to [thread starvation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html).

Answer (score 2):

> When there are multiple threads in waiting state; and if I call notify() rather than calling notifyAll() Which one is going to be notified among several threads in waiting state?

Although as has been mentioned, the particular behavior is not defined by the Java spec, I suspect that JDC implementations will take the thread at the front of the WAIT queue for the particular monitor.  However this should not be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) says:

> The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation.